# Create Linear System from derivatives of variables and solve it

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following simply function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = (x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + (2*z - C)^2 + (5 + z + x - 
     D)^2 + (y - 2 + 2*x)^2 + (y - z + F)^2
```

I am looking for a simple way to have mathematica take the derivatives w.r.t to `x,y,z`, set them to zero, create a system of 3 equations with the three unknowns where the unknowns are moved to the left, and the constants to the right (I need to see the system outputted before it is solved). I know how to do this the standard way where I write things down one step at a time, but I was wondering if there is simpler way to do it, because I have to deal with a messier function.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt what's in the begining [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7109/)

Comment: do you mean like `Solve[Table[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(q\)]\(f[x, y, z]\)\) == 
   0, {q, {x, y, z}}], {x, y, z}]`?

Comment: @julian Solve here doesn't work. I tried it ("his system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve").  Also it is really hard to read the output of that table.

Comment: Strange. Above code yields  `{{x -> 1/71 (-18 + 17 A - 13 B - 10 C + 12 D + 8 F), 
  y -> 1/71 (43 - 13 A + 35 B + 16 C - 5 D - 27 F), 
  z -> 1/71 (-49 - 5 A + 8 B + 28 C + 9 D + 6 F)}}` for me (M10)

Comment: The gradient is easily computed: `df = D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 1}]`. `Thread[df == 0]` should yield a system of equations you can feed to `Solve[]`.